# Spring 3.2 MVC @RequestParam unexpected decoding

Tags: spring-mvc, character-encoding, url-encoding

Consider following query string

```
siteId=360798&listingId=695332&stockFilename=6065/1mb%20&%20(Custom).jpg&uploadToken=2640861a8f06799416bae9d0a58839dd&username=Chuck%20Norris
```

I have the following on my MVC controller

```
@RequestParam("stockFilename") String stockFilename
```

I expect to get as value in my param to have **"6065/1mb & (Custom).jpg"**, yet the result is **"6065/1mb"**.  My first guess was that this was an encoding issue so I went to web.xml and looked at my encoding filter but this seems to be in order

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

Next up I went to look at my server setting

```
Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"
```

I've added the URIEncoding attribute, since I found an article explaining this as a possible culprit.  However it didn't fix my problem at all.  I'm actually out of ideas now I'm still quite sure it has to be an encoding issue, and spring is decoding it wrongly.  I'll continue searching but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this method and bean in your servlet-context :

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping;

public final class DoNotTruncateMyUrls implements BeanPostProcessor {
    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (bean instanceof RequestMappingHandlerMapping) {
            ((RequestMappingHandlerMapping)bean).setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
        }
        return bean;
    }
    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Bean :

```
<beans:bean class="com.packagename.DoNotTruncateMyUrls" />
```

Let me know if this works, or I have another solutions.

Comment: Also, if you are generating these URL's automatically, use URLSafe methods. A '/' is not a good idea in latter part of URL's.

Comment: The value of the parameter has been encoded with

URIUtil.encodeQuery(uri);

from the apache commons library, this should be a safe way to construct it.  But I just noticed that chuck%20norris param in the end as username DOES work as is, without any interference.  I'll try your solution in a bit, I'm a bit weary to do it right now since it might interfere with other controllers.  This is a fairly big legacy project where any change to the basic setup has major consequences

Comment: Why would it interfere with other controllers, it is only meant for checking URl's..It has got no connection to any controllers. If you are sending files over URL's and have file extensions embedded in URL, then you might need something different. Also, there is Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString available. It works nice.

Comment: I did notice it right now it's %20&%20 ... my & isn't encoded as it should !  no wonder it doesn't work, I've been blinded by the encoding issue I overlooked the & the entire time but that means that URIUtil.encodeQuery(uri); isn't doing it's job right !  I'll try the Base64.encodeBase64UrlSafeString one instead that might fix it

Comment: The answer was a working solution , however not what I needed, I was able to solve it by using the right url encoding library that would ALSO encode my & I overlooked the entire time